# Youtube Search in dash

Tags: unity, video, unity-dash, youtube

When I use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut in my Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, it only looks for videos in my hard disk or on dailymotion. I would really love to be able to search for youtube videos through unity dash. It seems like it was possible in the past, but is that the case now? Is there something wrong on my system, or is it simply because it wasn't designed to search on youtube? Can I obtain that function by adding a specific package? It seems like `atareao ppa` isn't working on that anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to *System Settings>Security and privacy>Search* and enable online search.

Comment: I already enabled the online search but it won't give me youtube results (nor show previews)